# Spring Boot bootJar mysql driver impl not getting injected by ServiceLoader

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jar

so I have a really strange problem with running a jar generated by Spring Boot's gradle task bootJar. I have a REST API that runs on top of mysql database, currently using
8.0.19 connector, so if I run `./gradlew.sh bootRun` everything is fine, but if I do `./gradlew.sh bootJar` to generate the jar and then run it, there is a problem 
with the loading of the mysql driver, more precisely I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl={myjdbcurl}`.

The first thing I did was to make sure that the jar has all other jar dependencies included inside `BOOT-INF/lib` and everything is fine there. So after I started debugging 
I noticed that due to some reason when `bootRun` is executed the driver is getting registered but during `bootJar` - it was not. So to narrow things down I got to the point
where `DriverManager` is actually registering the drivers and noticed that during running of the jar the following lines

```
ServiceLoader<Driver> loadedDrivers = ServiceLoader.load(Driver.class);
Iterator<Driver> driversIterator = loadedDrivers.iterator();
```

return no service implementation for the Driver, (and they do return the concrete impl when run during `bootRun`). The definition of the driver is 
`/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` where the class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` which is fine, but I don't get why this service is not found
during running of the jar, any ideas how to find out the reason and a possible fix? Is there a possibility that the service impl might be exluded from bootJar or something similar ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for everyone having the same problem, here is the solution:

I was using HikariCP as data source and was defining my config

```
    config.setPoolName(metadata.getPoolName());
    config.setJdbcUrl(metadata.getJDBCUrl());
    config.setUsername(metadata.getUsername());
    config.setPassword(metadata.getPassword());
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);
```

due to some strange reason when I assemble a jar with the following config DriverManager which uses `ServiceLoader` does not find META-INF/services and the implementation is not injected, therefore an error was thrown that there is no available driver. If I start the app not as a JAR - there is no such problem.

so to solve this - just add `.config.setDriverClassName(yourDriverClass)` - it will implicitly load the driver instead of relying on `ServiceLoader` to find the impl. However, it still remains a mystery why `ServiceLoader` is not able to find META-INF/services from mysql.jar, when executed from jar.